# How to fix element.videoHeight in js with WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, height, width

I need some serious help about my code which is driving me crazy !!
I'm trying to set the format of my video to match a square rendering but my js won't set the element.videoHeight to the value I've defined !

I feel like I tried everything : changing the video.height AND video.videoHeight in multiple places, trying the 'loadedmetadata' method, clearing all cookies and caches etc...

Here's my current code:

```
(function ()
{
    let width = 0;
    let height = 0;
    let streaming = false;
    let video = null;
    let canvas = null;

    function startup()
    {
        video = document.getElementById('webcam');
        canvas = document.getElementById('transit');

        width = video.offsetWidth;
        video.width = width;
        video.height = width;
        document.getElementById('transit').width = width;
        document.getElementById('result').width = width;

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: width, height: width }, audio: false })
            .then(function(stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log("An error occured: " + err);
            });

        video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev){
            if (!streaming) {
                height = width;

                video.setAttribute('width', width);
                video.setAttribute('height', width);
                canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
                canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
                streaming = true;
            }
        }, false);
window.addEventListener('load', startup, false);
})();
```

I want the video.videoWidth to be equal to video.videoHeight.
But event if I manage to change the video.videoWidth in my code (according to some console.log), the video.videoHeight stays the same !

The result is like if I put a div around my  tag and the div is a square, but the video itself is still in some kind of 4/3 format !
And oddly enough, it works just fine on my personal computer, but it doesn't on some other one, both of them being Mac OSX... And with the same js version obviously.

Help ! :'(

Answer (score 0):

videoHeight is a read-only property, see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/videoHeight).

To get a square rendering (even if the video is 4:3) use the CSS 'cover' [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) combined with width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, thank you for your answer but I found the error : it was because the definition of the video can't exceed 720px in height !!
So I just added a condition stating that :

```
if (video.offsetHeight > 720)
    width = 720;
else
    width = video.offsetWidth;
```

So now I can have a square video rendering :)